# Comma usage confusion

Tags: commas, conjunctions

Here's the sentence given in my book:

> Beyond that I know nothing.

Shouldn't this be the following?

> Beyond that, I know nothing.

If I'm wrong, could you please explain the precise rules? As far as I know, subordinating conjunctions that begin a sentence with a dependent clause require a comma after. Is "beyond" acting as a subordinating conjunction and "that" as a dependent clause here?

I'm confused.

Comment: *Beyond* is a preposition and *that* is the object of the preposition. Your style guide of choice will advise you as to how short your introductory prepositional phrase must be to avoid a comma. Some say two words. Some say five. It's never wrong to use a comma though.

Comment: @TinfoilHat It, can be, wrong to, use a, comma.

Comment: @CJDennis: I meant it's never wrong to use a comma after a very short introductory prepositional phrase. *At midnight I went to bed. At midnight, I went to bed.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat without a comma in this example, there is some ambiguity as to whether "that" is a pronoun or a conjunction.

Comment: @phoog: As *Beyond that I know nothing* is a complete sentence here, *that* can only be a demonstrative pronoun. Still, style-wise, the use of a comma would be polite so the reader doesn't need to get to the end of the sentence to confirm that.